# How to highlight elasticsearch terms with tags_schema?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm having trouble figuring how to use the `tags_schema` feature described at https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-highlighting.html --

Given a query with two terms, "foo" and "bar", I'd like "foo" to be highlighted differently from "bar". The docs linked above make it seem like `tags_schema` can be used to apply a class to the `<em>` tag that highlights each term, but I can't figure out how to get that working.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example:

```
GET _search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "message": "error"
    }
  },
  "highlight": {
    "fields": {"message": {}},
    "tags_schema": "styled"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but that gives me the same `<em class="hlt1">` tags on every match, even if the terms that matched were different. I'd like to see `class="hlt1"` on any "foo" matches and `class="hlt2"` on any "bar" matches (for example).

Comment: The documentation at https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-highlighting.html#configure-tags seems to imply that you need to enable the fvh on the fields for this to work:

> "When using the fast vector highlighter, you can specify additional tags and the "importance" is ordered."

Comment: we used fvh to achieve what Hugh need but it's not working as expected. Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53042482/highlight-term-issue-with-wild-card-in-query-string for more information